# Need advice on selecting Rails or PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

Our current website runs Joomla. However, we are finding increasingly that our demands are being restricted by the frame because it is not a blog or real content managed site.

Our site is not particularly complicated - we need an admin area (manage clients, customers, general visitors) and to manage advert/business listings; we need a way of displaying the listings of ads/businesses in a nice manner, etc. Hence there is no real use (¿for?) major features.

Joomla, although nice CMS, is stopping us by restricting how we layout the site, position elements, module issues, etc.

Hence, we started investigating using Rails (because we are really more programmers the web designers). After some time playing with Rails 3/3.1 we were find it fairly nice and usable.

However, because our hosting is shared, CPanel only has Rails 2.3 installed.

Now seeing that Rails 2 and Rails 3 are quite different:

Would there be a point of moving our test sites back to Rails 2
or
Would it be better to use something like code-igniter  for PHP until CPanel has Rails 3 support?

Comment: I really think the people voting to close this are only reading the subject line. It's not flame bait, even though it appears that it would be. The real question is "Is it worth it to switch to Rails if the only version available is 2.3?" Clearly, that's not his only option, but that's the crux of the immediate issue.

Comment: Thanks jdl - that is probably a good way to put it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your choice based on your which one you are most comfortable programming with, not what your current shared hosting environment works best with. If this is a really small app (the **only** kind of app where it would be appropriate to use a shared hosting environment) then you can host your app for free on a service like [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/pricing#1-0). If the app isn't super small your shared hosting account probably won't cut it long term no matter what tool set you go with.

Even if this is a hobby project or something you can likely get a virtual/cloud server for about the same price (or less) as your shared host, opening up the door to using any version of anything. Hell, you could install Tomcat/JBOSS/etc and write the app in Java if you want (though my preference would absolutely be Rails :-)

Choose which one is easier to develop, then make changes to your hosting solution to make it compatible with your choice. If you have existing PHP apps or other "stuff" on your shared host, it is pretty easy to set up Apache/nginx to play nice with both PHP and Ruby apps running on the same box.

Lastly, the choice shouldn't be between Rails or PHP, it should be between Rails and one of the many great frameworks PHP has to offer. You really should use a framework, even if its just a lightweight one. My PHP favorite is Code Igniter. If you like Ruby but want something lighter weight, check out Sinatra.

Comment: Unfortunately for db size is already 40MB and set to grow some more so heroku is not really too much of an option. I am checking out the other PHP frameworks and I'll look into Sinatra as well. Thanks.

Comment: I still think you should start looking at alternatives to your shared host environment. They are quickly being replaced by small virtual servers and for good reason. Amazon EC2/S3 also has a free tier (http://aws.amazon.com/free/) with 1GB of DB space available. My personal fave is Rackspace Cloud Servers, which don't have a free tier, but a 512mb instance should probably be enough and is only ~$10/month.

Comment: Thanks - I will check that out. Being outside the US and with a currency that is very week, the $ costs tend to turn into quite large equivalent costs in our currency. Doing anything here other than shared hosting can cost over the $40 mark. Even local hosting of Rails adds a huge price tag to have it added on to SLA.

Comment: I see. I'm sure cloud hosting options will improve in your country... eventually. Hopefully its sooner rather than later. If you go with Rails 2.3 and your current host, just make sure you are careful to make the app 2.3 **and** 3.1 compatible so you can move when local hosting options improve or when your host upgrades the version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Our local telco is set to release unlimited broadband so they can do IPTV at the end 2012/mid-2013. Hopefully this will enable better local hosting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you will be handling the codebase yourselves, I'd suggest using CodeIgniter. It is not a CMS, but a framework for your application. It's easy to learn and very robust.

That said, you would have to build the application from the ground up (perhaps re-use some existing code you have in Joomla), but the rewards will outweigh the costs in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks - it is our code base. We were already building it from scratch with Rails, so we reuse the db schema etc.

Answer (score 0):

My cpanel from hostgator would only install Ruby 2, so I just installed the latest versions by going into the SSH and running install commands... assuming you have vps. Im sure you could run update commands to get you running in the latest ruby/rails setup.

Codeigniter is great, and I use it for small sites that need a lot of custom little things or personality in the backend, its expandable, and pretty easy to learn. The best part about it is the documentation/forums. I'm always grabbing code an extending the way I want easily and quickly.

But the two are really different, go with whatever your comfortable with.

I myself went from php to ruby/rails. I've been using Radiant CMS, RefineryCMS. They're both great!

Comment: I would love to have able to do that, by SSH is not allowed :(